# sed replace positional match of unknown string divided by user-defined separator

Tags: sed, replace, tar

Want to rename the (known) 3th folder within a (unknown) file path from a string, when positioned on 3th level while separator is `/`

Need a one-liner explicitly for `sed`. Because I later want use it for `tar --transform=EXPRESSION`

```
string="/db/foo/db/bar/db/folder"
echo "$string" | sed 's,db,databases,'
```

sed replace "db" only on 3th level

expected result

```
/db/foo/databases/bar/db/folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to capture `/db/foo/` and then match `db`. Then use use the first caputring group in the replacement using `\1`:

```
string="/db/foo/db/bar/db/folder"
echo -e "$string" | sed 's,^\(/[^/]*/[^/]*/\)db,\1databases,'
```

About the pattern

- `^` Start of string
- `\(` Start capture group

  - `/[^/]*/[^/]*/` Match the first 2 parts using a negated character class
- `\)` Close capture group
- `db` Match literally

That will give you

```
/db/foo/databases/bar/db/folder
```

Answer (score 1):

If awk is also an option for this task:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} $4=="db"{$4="database"} 1' <<<'/db/foo/db/bar/db/folder'
/db/foo/database/bar/db/folder
```

- `FS = OFS = "/"` assign `/` to both input and output field separators,
- `$4 == "db" { $4 = "database }"` if fourth field is `db`, make it `database`,
- `1` print the record.

Comment: I suspect the OP just wants to set the 4th field regardless of it's existing value so then it'd just be `{$4="database"}`. Maybe include that as an option?

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for reminding me, updated. I'm not sure about that. I mean if it was so, why would he try `s,db,databases,`?

Comment: "db" is the search pattern for replacement - if no match, keep field untouched

Comment: @oguzismail I thought she was doing `s,db,databases` because `db` just happened to be in the right field and she couldn't figure out how to do it otherwise with sed. I see @anubhava thought the same thing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344105/1745001). That's the problem with just a single line of sample input/output - it's just not adequate to clarify/demonstrate requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure bash way to get this done by setting `IFS=/` without calling any external utility:

```
string="/db/foo/db/bar/db/folder"
string=$(IFS=/; read -a arr <<< "$string"; arr[3]='databases'; echo "${arr[*]}")
echo "$string"
```

```
/db/foo/databases/bar/db/folder
```