# Bash: Find and replace lines in a file using the lines of another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace, file-io

I have two files: `masterlist.txt` that has hundreds of lines of URLs, and `toupdate.txt` that has a smaller number of updated versions of lines from the `masterlist.txt` file that need to be replaced.

I'd like to be able to automate this process using Bash, since the creation and utilisation of these lists is already occuring in a bash script.

The server part of the URL is the part that changes, so we could match using the unique part: `/whatever/whatever_user.xml`, but how to find and replace those lines in `masterlist.txt`? i.e. how to go through each line of `toupdate.txt` and as it ends in `/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml`, find that ending in `masterlist.txt` and replace that whole line with the new one?

So `https://123456url.domain.com/26/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml` becomes `https://new-123.domain.com/1/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml` for example.

The rest of `masterlist.txt` needs to stay intact, so we must only find and replace lines that have different servers for the same line endings (IDs).

#### Structure

`masterlist.txt` looks like this:

```
https://123456url.domain.com/26/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml
https://456789url.domain.com/32/path/f_AnotherName/f_AnotherName_user.xml
https://101112url.domain.com/1/path/g_SomethingElse/g_SomethingElse_user.xml
https://222blah11.domain.com/19/path/e_BlahBlah/e_BlahBlah_user.xml
[...]
```

`toupdate.txt` looks like this:

```
https://new-123.domain.com/1/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml
https://foo-254.domain.com/8/path/g_SomethingElse/g_SomethingElse_user.xml
```

### Desired Result

Make `masterlist.txt` look like:

```
https://new-123.domain.com/1/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml
https://456789url.domain.com/32/path/f_AnotherName/f_AnotherName_user.xml
https://foo-254.domain.com/8/path/g_SomethingElse/g_SomethingElse_user.xml
https://222blah11.domain.com/19/path/e_BlahBlah/e_BlahBlah_user.xml
[...]
```

### Initial workup

I've looked at `sed` but I don't know how to do the find and replace using lines from the two files?

Here's what I have so far, doing the file handling at least:

```
#!/bin/bash

#...

while read -r line; do
    # there's a new link on each line
    link="${line}"
    # extract the unique part from the end of each line
    grabXML="${link##*/}"
    grabID="${grabXML%_user.xml}"
    # if we cannot grab the ID, then just set it to use the full link so we don't have an empty string
    if [ -n "${grabID}" ]; then
        identifier=${grabID}
    else
        identifier="${line}"
    fi
    
    ## the find and replace here? ##    

# we're done when we've reached the end of the file
done < "masterlist.txt"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078 https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55343129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A map
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (/[^/]+/[^/]*\.xml)$ ]]; then
        uniq_part="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        map[$uniq_part]=$line
    fi
done < "toupdate.txt"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (/[^/]+/[^/]*\.xml)$ ]]; then
        uniq_part="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if [[ -n ${map[$uniq_part]} ]]; then
            line=${map[$uniq_part]}
        fi
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < "masterlist.txt" > "masterlist_tmp.txt"

# if the result of "masterlist_tmp.txt" is good enough, uncomment the line below
# mv -f -- "masterlist_tmp.txt" "masterlist.txt"
```

result:

```
https://new-123.domain.com/1/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml
https://456789url.domain.com/32/path/f_AnotherName/f_AnotherName_user.xml
https://foo-254.domain.com/8/path/g_SomethingElse/g_SomethingElse_user.xml
https://222blah11.domain.com/19/path/e_BlahBlah/e_BlahBlah_user.xml
```

**[Explanations]**

- The associative array `map` maps the "unique part" such as `/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml` to the "full path" such as `https://new-123.domain.com/1/path/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml`.
- The regex `(/[^/]+/[^/]*\.xml)$`, if matched, assigns the shell variable
  `BASH_REMATCH[1]` to the substring from the second rightmost slash
  to the extention ".xml" at the end of the string.
- In the first loop on the file "toupdate.txt", it generates "unique part"
  and "fill path" pairs as key-value pairs of the associative array.
- In the second loop on the file "masterlist.txt", the extracted
  "unique part" is tested if the associated value exists. If so, the
  line is substituted with the associated value, the line in "toupdate.txt"
  file.

**[Alternative]**
If the text files are large in size, `bash` may not be fast enough. In such a case, `awk` script will work more efficiently:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    if (match($0, "/[^/]+/[^/]*\\.xml$")) {
        map[substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)] = $0
    }
    next
}
{
    if (match($0, "/[^/]+/[^/]*\\.xml$")) {
        full_path = map[substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)]
        if (full_path != "") {
            $0 = full_path
        }
    }
    print
}' "toupdate.txt" "masterlist.txt" > "masterlist_tmp.txt"
```

**[Explanations]**

- The `NR==FNR { BLOCK1; next } { BLOCK2 }` syntax is a common idiom to
  switch the processing individually for each file. As the `NR==FNR` condition
  meets only for the 1st file in the argument list and `next` statement skips
  the following block, `BLOCK1` processes the file "toupdate.txt" only.
  Similarly `BLOCK2` processes the file "masterlist.txt" only.
- If the function `match($0, pattern)` succeeds, it sets the `awk` variable
  `RSTART` to the start position of the matched substring out of `$0`,
  the current record read from the file,
  then sets the variable `RLENGTH` to the length of the matched substring.
  Now we can extract the matched substring such as
  `/f_SomeName/f_SomeName_user.xml` by using the `substr()` function.
- Then we assign the array `map` so that the substring (the unique part)
  is mapped to the whole url in "toupdate.txt".
- The second block works mostly similar to the first block. If the value corresponding to the key
  is found in the array `map`, then the record ($0) is replaced with the
  value of the array indexed by the key.

Comment: I like the `awk` answer! Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how the `awk` answer works, please?

Comment: @nooblag Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113 for an explanation of a similar `awk` command.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added small explanations of the `awk` script in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have `sed` write its own script - producing the desired output,

```
sed -e "$(sed -e 's<^\(http[s]*://[^/]*/[^/]*/\)\(.*\)<\\|\2\$| s|.*|\1\2|<' toupdate.txt)" masterlist.txt
```

where

- the inner `sed` command has an outer and an inner `s`ubstitution command
- outer `s` (`s<...<...<`) captures scheme://domain/N/ as `\1` and rest-of-path
  `\(.*\)` as `\2` and inserts them into a script for the outer `sed` command
- outer `sed` script (`\|\2$| s|.*|\1\2|`) finds URLs in `masterlist.txt` ending in
  rest-of-path, substituting (inner `s`) the new URL from `toupdate.txt`
- to avoid a lot of backslash-escaping `<` and `|` are used as
  delimiters for the two `s` commands, and `\|...|` is used for `/.../`

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, I should note that `...` is not literal, I'm using an ellipsis there in the excerpt of the `masterlist.txt` to denote "and so on." I'll add some brackets to help clear that up?

Comment: @nooblag Yes. In my explanation I used `...` instead of an ellipsis sign (U+2026), not as a literal; and I understood yours to be an ellipsis, too.